# cppcheck Non-local variable 'xxx' will use pointer to local variable 'config'

Tags: c++, cppcheck

[image]
This is my code.I'm use cppcheck check my code,error log display Non-local variable 'm_curServer' will use pointer to local variable 'config'.

I am a novice.I don't know what to do about it.I hope to get your help. thanks!

Comment: what is this fuction suppoed to do? It isnt that obvious, because as it stands it stores a pointer to a temporary, which is nonsense. Do you actually want to store a pointer to the parameter passed by the called?

Comment: asked differently: Why is `m_curServer` a pointer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please review [ask], in particular the parts about not posting images of code.

Comment: Its function is to reset the server

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a pointer to a function-local variable `config` which after returning from `resetCurServer` will be a dangling pointer.

Instead you should just assign by value

```
class ServerConfigOptDlg {
public:
    resetCurServer(ServerConfig config);
private:
    ServerConfig m_curServer;
}

void ServerConfigOptDlg::resetCurServer(ServerConfig config) {
    m_curServer = config;
}
```

Or if you need pointer semantics, you should use managed pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`

```
#include <memory>

class ServerConfigOptDlg {
private:
    resetCurServer(std::unique_ptr<ServerConfig> config);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<ServerConfig> m_curServer;
}

void ServerConfigOptDlg::resetCurServer(std::unique_ptr<ServerConfig> config) {
    m_curServer = std::move(config);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help.I solved this problem